# Execute multiple sqoop commands from a file

Tags: sqoop

I have multiple sqoop commands, and I want to execute them sequentially. How can I do this.

Currently, --options-file allows us to execute one command at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is possible only with Sqoop but for my case i have used Oozie to execute multiple Sqoop commands.

Comment: I know that with Oozie, multiple sqoop commands can be executed. In my scenario, I am using a SSIS package to manage the overall process. And I did some research, sqoop can not execute multiple commands together.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me a cool idea to execute a Oozie task in my SSIS package. Here Oozie will execute multiple sqoop commands.

Answer (score 2):

Use shell script. Write commands one by one and execute the script.It will definitely work.

```
    #!/bin/bash


echo "*************SQOOP IMPORT JOB UTILITY*******************"

# First Sqoop command
echo
sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/<DB> --table TABLE_NAME_1  --username user -password pass -m 1 2> log1.txt

# Second Sqoop command
echo
sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/<DB> --table TABLE_NAME_2  --username user -password pass -m 1 2> log2.txt

echo "Check log file for sqoop jobs status"
```

Run shell script

```
./myscript.sh
```